# Request had invalid authentication credentials, what to do? R Studio

Tags: r, bigrquery

```
 Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project. [authError] 

<error/bigrquery_authError>
Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project. [authError] 
Backtrace:
 1. bigrquery::bq_table_download(...)
 5. bigrquery:::bq_check_response(...)
 6. bigrquery:::signal_reason(json$error$errors[[1L]]$reason, json$error$message)
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.
```

Can someone please help, how to fix this? I'm downloading a huge table with millions of lines, it stuck in 12% and returns this error.

Comment: This is R but not R Studio; R Studio is only an IDE, it usually doesn't matter which IDE you're running under, or console. More important is that the package you were running is `bigrquery`.